# Chicken bone broth, what is the brown stuff at the bottom of the pot?

Tags: broth, bones, chicken-stock

I often make chicken bone broth using a simple recipe of chicken backs, chicken feet, water, apple cider vinegar, parsley, salt.  Ingredients are organic.  The resulting broth tastes excellent.

My concern is the brown crud at the bottom of the pot.  Pictures below.  What is this?  Is it normal?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Looks like sediment from stuff like the marrow settling out of the rest of the stock. You could avoid that by skimming the froth and brown bits when it's boiling, but it's otherwise not a problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could be a lot of things, depending on how clean the bones were, but assuming everything was clean, then my guess would be bone marrow. It's exactly that color and texture:

[image: Raw Bone Marrow]

(Source: [My Life As A Foodie](http://www.mylifeasafoodie.com/2011/01/18/roasted-bone-marrow-with-parsley-salad/))

It gets darker when cooked - refer to the link above for more photos. Don't worry about safety, bone marrow is nutritious and delicious.

You're more likely to end up with marrow in your broth if any of the bones were cut, cracked, or broken, either intentionally or during the cooking process.

Answer (score 0):

It's coagulated protein and particulates from the bones. Nothing to worry about. If you want crystal clear broth, you can make a consomme with a raft of egg whites (though usually ground meat is also used). Any classic French cookbook will have instructions for this; I refer to Julia Child's *The Way to Cook*.